# Phonegap CSS translate3d get buggy after phone sleep

Tags: android, css, cordova, transform

I'm doing an app for Android in PhoneGap (latest). I've added some translate3d based transitions which are working fine. Than switch off the screen for a while with the power button (not pause/quit app). When i turn on the screen again, animations are not working or got really buggy. Any workaround for this? Or is there an event to detect the state when switching on the screen so i can trigger a redraw.

Comment: Have you tried on another device? In my experience Phonegap tends to act very differently even when it's another device running the same OS. Personally I've never had this issue running translate3d in my Phonegap apps.

Comment: It only does only on my phone so far (Stock Android 4.2.2). Hope it does only for me (which is a nice dream). The app becomes unusable after. It would be nice to catch screen off / on but it has no built in events for that.

Comment: It doesn't, no. You'd have to write a specific Android plugin and add to your Phonegap project. Even though this dosen't sound like a sensible solution to me. You could try and use the live debugging tool offered by build.phonegap to try and trace the problems.